# Estimating distributed capacitance from frequency sweep

Tags: capacitance, parasitic-capacitance, distributed

I have a top/bottom spiral planar coil with the following frequency response. Is it correct to assume that the distributed capacitance is the sum of the capacitance values calculated over all the resonance points?

C1 calculated at first resonance 716kHz, L=499uH   (~95pF)

C2 calculated at second resonance 4Mhz, L=499uH (~3.17pF)

etc .. with total Cd as the sum of these?

[image: Sweep]

Comment: It is assumed that L is not constant at 2 or more resonant frequencies?

Comment: Even if you did have a value for what you want, what use is that value? Ditto what Antonio says. Also consider transmission line effects at higher frequencies.

Comment: The coil is used in a high frequency (for that power level), high voltage, transformer. The secondary parasitic winding capacitance will be reflected to the primary as a multiple of the high step up ratio. This parasitic participates in a resonant network in a resonant converter. It is part of characterizing the overall network.

Comment: @Antonio51 I am little unsure, usually it seems methods for estimating parasitic capacitance assume a pure inductor for the sake of resonant calculations. The graph contains also a line (blue) for inductance but i honestly dont know if it is valid / measurable there around resonance.

Comment: @Stonie Around resonance, it is "not valid" ... "Inductor" at left, "capacitor" at right (?). But perhaps ok for validating OP's question. Will search.